# How to make a single virtualbox window full screen

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors and a VM in virtual box with two displays, which gives me two separate windows. Is it possible to make only one of these VirtualBox windows full screen?

Comment: Have you tried `Host + C` ? This should make the VirtualBox window full screen instead of scaled. Remember: if you found an answer that helped solve your problem, mark it as solved!

Comment: You can just change the display dimensions in your virtual machine to those of your target monitor device. In minimized mode it will contains a scrollbar to navigate it but if you go full screen you will have your desired goal achieved.

Answer (score 27):

I was also facing same issue.

I installed 6.0.8 form [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) on my **windows** machine then installed **ubuntu-19.04.**

When I start it, got s*mall window screen*.

I looked for that in many articles such as-

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/314685/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-fullscreen-on-virtualbox
2. https://superuser.com/questions/930184/maximizing-window-for-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Last article advice me to install some **Guest Additions from Virtual Box** but that also didn't worked.

> solution was very small and easy-

1. Login to the ubuntu machine.
2. Look for `settings > Devices`.
3. Changed Resolution as **1920 x 1200**.
4. Clicked **Apply**.
5. Choose "**keep configuration**".

That produced required result.
*Note- You may have different regularization size. sometime may not have suitable resolution.*

Hope will help you!

Comment: this did it. thank you sir

Comment: Worked like a charm. Very simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 23):

If you want to make a VM window to be full screen, you have to install the Guest Additions package in your VM. To do so, you have to:

1. Once you have launched your VM, in the top menú, select "Devices -> Install Guest Additions". After that, the Guest Additions .iso will be loaded.
2. You will see the .iso loaded as a CD image. Run it and it will launch the install process in a Terminal. Follow the instructions until the end of the install process.
3. Reboot your VM.

After that, you will be able to make the VM window full screen, or any size that you want.

Comment: Thanks VinsanityL. I can make windows full screen, the problem is both windows go full screen at the same time. What I am trying to is to make one of them full screen on one monitor, and keep the one just maximised on my second monitor

Comment: In that case, you can take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/2912/how-can-i-get-virtualbox-to-play-nicely-with-dual-monitors and see Justin's answer. Maybe, if you create a xorg.conf with the Screen Modes with the resolution, you can get a different size for each window.

Comment: Here my solution: Given: CentOs7 : Fullscreen (Windows 10)not work on Oracle VirtualBox's 6.1 machine
Solution: 
     1. Update CentOS 7 kernel to ver. 5.12+
     2. On VirtualBox's machine settings: /Display -> Turn On "Enable 3D Acceleration"/
     3. On VirtualBox's menu: /Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image/
     4. Restart Virtual machine

Answer (score 4):

another way is to go to settings>display and change scale factor to 200%

Comment: It looks horrible, too pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for which I wish to share a solution.
I have only 1 monitor (max 2560x1440) but I could only get max 1920x1200. Going Full screen (Right-Cntrl F) or dragging window edges only showed me 1920x1200 with a black border.
I changed Graphics Controller from VboxVGA (will be removed in future according to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=93941) to VMSVGA (recommended for Linux Guests) and rebooted.
Everything was the same until I used Windows 10 host Maximize button which enabled proper full screen (2560x1360) and I can now drag window edges to get any resolution, not just std resolutions.
My system is
Host: Windows 10
VirtualBox: 6.1.4
Guest Additions: 6.1.5 (due to copy/paste problem with GA 6.1.4)
Client: Ubuntu 18.04.